# Genymotion VirtualBox error

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion and VirtualBox on my computer, and set up a Samsung Galaxy S6 device through Genymotion. However, when I try to start the device, Genymotion gives me this error:

> Unable to start the virtual device
>
> VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device
>
> To find out the cause the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox.
>
> For more information, check the log files. Please refer to:www.genymotion.com/faq/logs

I try to start the device in VirtualBox, and get this error:
[Virtualbox Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtfMg.jpg)

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine **Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560**
>
> ▼ Details
>
> The configured driver wasn't found. Either the necessary driver modules wasn't loaded, the name was misspelled, or it was a misconfiguration. (VERR_PDM_DRIVER_NOT_FOUND).
>
> Result Code: 
>   E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>   Component: 
>   ConsoleWrap
>   Interface: 
>   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I have tried to delete the network drivers and have Genymotion reinstall them. I have also checked all of the drivers for the network interface [(drivers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6FLq.jpg), but nothing seems to help. What should I do?

Comment: Was about to ask about this problem too!  Fixed this by updating the settings for the emulated device.  `Settings`->`Audio Icon`->`Select a value for Host Audio Driver`.  This was blank for me but I could set it to `CoreAudio`.

Comment: @zec I can set the Host Audio Driver to either `Windows DirectSound` or `Null Audio Driver` and the Audio Controller to `Intel HD Audio`, `ICH AC97`, or `SoundBlaster 16`. However, the `OK` button is greyed out for all possible combinations of those options. It says "Invalid settings detected". However, I have just clicked on the invalid settings popup, and it tells me that there is not enough memory on my computer for the OS. I will be back in 15 min with an update. (Thank you @zec for leading me to this!)

Comment: no worries! it's what this site is for.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had this same problem when I installed Genymotion on MacOSX. Solved it by disabling audio.

1. Open Virtual Box
2. Select Android VM ( Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560 in your case)
3. Click *Settings* on top.
4. Go to *Audio* and **Uncheck** *Enable Audio Checkbox*

Comment: Works too if you choose a valid driver in the same setting, at step 4. Actually, I updated Genymotion via RDP and somehow it fell back to an empty audio driver setting.

Comment: I just had to select _Core Audio_ as the _Host Audio Driver_) under _Audio_ instead of unchecking audio entirely.

Comment: it's valid for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and went through the above steps except step 4 that I made it enable and chose a proper Audio Driver which was available on my Windows 7.

I had the same problem and went through the above steps provided by 
[ygogia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2613615/ygogia)

> 1. Open Virtual Box
> 2. Select Android VM ( Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560 in your case)
> 3. Click Settings on top.
> 4. Go to Audio and Uncheck Enable Audio Checkbox

**except step 4 that I made it enable** and chose a proper Audio Driver which was available on my Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.
I had to follow the steps below in order for the Android OS to load:
1. Open Virtual Box
2. Click Start after Selecting the the Virtual device from Genymotion App.
Thanks Ygogia..